# Need help with a power supply outputs

Tags: power-supply

Following is a power supply with dual +-15V output:

http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/13f8/0900766b813f8a87.pdf

I'm confused to understand two points:

1-) What is the difference between Output A and Output C ? Both looks variable. One is 1A the other is 0.2 A. I cannot figure out what is the difference. For dual op-Amps which one should be used?

2-) It also says 0 to 30V. How can it be configured for that? Output A with +15 plus and -15 GND?

Comment: Some of the statements on that brochure don't make sense to me.  I'd want to look at a proper user manual or schematic diagram to determine what voltages are really available under what circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

> 1-) What is the difference between Output A and Output C ? Both looks variable. One is 1A the other is 0.2 A. I cannot figure out what is the difference. For dual op-Amps which one should be used?

OUTPUT A is a pair of tracking outputs. Press the OUTPUT SELECTION button and the OUTPUT A LED will probably blink (I didn't check). Pressing the up/down keys will cause both to be adjusted. e.g., ±15, ±14, ±13, etc., or in 0.1 V steps. Use these for dual rail opamps.

OUTPUT C is a second single supply adjustable independently between -15 and +15 V. This could be useful, for example, to apply a DC voltage into your opamp circuit.

> 2-) It also says 0 to 30V. How can it be configured for that? Output A with +15 plus and -15 GND?

[image]

You're right - it can't. It's 30 V between the blue and the red socket but that will only be useful if you don't need the COM reference. It will be symmetrical around the COM terminal.

[image]

Wow!

Comment: I want to buy a cheap power supply with variable outputs and +-15V split supply option. This is the only one I could find in RS. Would you recommend it for hobby projects?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. You've already identified one limitation. I would be inclined to get a single adjustable supply and a fixed ±12 or ±15 V supply for the opamps. You generally don't need much current for these but the big adjustable can be used to charge batteries, etc.

Comment: I don't want to have two supplies and I dont want to waste time for creating split supplies each time. The two output ones are easy to make split but they are expensive. What could limit me if I use this one?

Comment: This doesnt have current limiting. Is that a big problem?

Comment: The lack of current limiting _is_ a problem. It's a very useful feature when powering up a circuit, device or motor that may have a fault. It reduces the possibility of damage. The other problem is the lack of flexibility because the COMs are all internally connected.

Comment: I spent long time and could not find any cheap supply which has both current limiting and +-15V in the market. I might buy this but Im afraid to regret later. Btw one more question: When would you use Output C? Lets say you need +9V, Which variable output would you choose A or C?, why?

Comment: "_I'm afraid to regret later._" You'll always find a use for it. "_Lets say you need +9V, Which variable output would you choose A or C?, Why?_" Use the lowest one that provides enough current. Power will be limited in a fault.

Comment: they have also this version: http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/13f8/0900766b813f8a94.pdf has better features but not split supply.

Comment: Sorry, you've turned this into a shopping question and they're not allowed. See the Help Center.

Answer (score 0):

output A:
you can select any two voltages (blue, red) in the range of -15V to +15V, that is 0v to -15v is obtained from the blue colored terminal , 0v to +15v is obtained from the red colored terminal.

output C:
it is a single output terminal through which we can obtain only one voltage in -15v to +15v interval

for op-amps we use output A.

if -15v is considered as the reference voltage, output A behaves as 0 to 30v variable power supply.

Comment: When would you use Output C? Lets say you need +9V, Which output would you choose? Why?

Comment: It depends on the current. We usually choose low currents and so using output C is better.